# What is ruby equivalent to volatile in Java?

Tags: ruby, caching, concurrency

I have Ruby code with global data structure that a number of threads modify concurrently. I have some evidence that show that CPU caches keep replicas of this data structures and once one thread modifies the global data structure, other threads stay with the old version of this data structure in the cache.

In Java, there is a "volatile" keyword that resolves this problem. A volatile in Java means that the data will be read directly from main memory, and not from CPU cache.

Do you know if this feature exists in Ruby? I tried to work with [Concurrent::Atom](https://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/1.1.4/Concurrent/Atom.html), but it still didn't resolve my problem.

This is the code I wrote:

```
class CacheClass
  include Singleton
    
  EXPIRATION_TIME = 10.minutes

  def initialize
    @data = Concurrent::Atom.new([])
    @last_update = Concurrent::Atom.new(nil)
    @mutex = Mutex.new
    load
  end

  def fetch(refresh_data = false)
    load_data_if_time_period_elapsed if refresh_data
    @data.value || []
  end

  def load_data_if_time_period_elapsed
    @mutex.synchronize do
      if data_expired?
        @last_update.swap{ Time.now }
        Thread.new { load }
      end
    end
  end

  def data_expired?
    @last_update.value.blank? || ((Time.now - @last_update.value) > EXPIRATION_TIME)
  end

  def load
    logger.info "Started loading"
    @data.swap { cache_data }
    @last_update.swap { Time.now }
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    # handle errors
  end
end
```

The method 'load' is called many times a second. As you can expect I see the log "Started loading" once in 10 minutes. However, whenever I see this log it appears 4 times with a time gap of few seconds, and then this log is silent for 10 minutes.

Comment: I have no knowledge of ruby threads keeping a replica/cache of global variables. I'd be interested to know what evidence/resource you have to back this up.

Comment: FYI: You can write correct, multi-threaded Java code without ever using the `volatile` keyword. In fact, `volatile` is a tricky optimization that most programmers probably should avoid using. Every form of _mutual exclusion,_ in Java (e.g., `Lock` objects, and `synchronized` blocks)  also solves the same problem that `volatile` solves. I don't know Ruby, but I would expect the same from Ruby's `Mutex` class.

Comment: Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent. Reading from main memory is an incorrect mental model; this is not how modern CPUs work.

Comment: @TomLord I edited the post. I posted the code and explained what I see in the logs.

Comment: It appears that you are referencing an array as the value in your `Atom`. Here, you have to make sure that nobody changes the array outside of your `CacheClass` (which is entirely possible right now). If the array is mutated, all references to it will also show the updates, regardless of any cache references.

Comment: Also, the `load` in `load_data_if_time_period_elapsed` might be run after the mutex was given up as you explicitly run it in new Thread. In any case, you design looks needlessly complex and inconsistently. You might get better responses if you describe what you are trying to achieve in the end rather than trying to come up with justifications for your current design (to solve the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)).

Comment: @HolgerJust
There are other considerations that I didn't mention in order to keep the post as short as possible. Also, I know that the operation of Thread.new { load } takes place outside the mutext. The point is that last_update is updated inside the mutex, and if another thread enters the critical code during the operation of thread, then data_expired? has to be false.